# App review rejection. How to use CloudKit? Or what is CloudKit for?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, cloudkit

I am developing a chat app that uses CloudKit to authenticate the users, store data on the cloud and then exchange content between users.

Initially, according to the reviewer following guideline was breached when asking user to have an iCloud account setup on the device to make use of app entire set of functionality.

**5.1 Privacy**

**5.1.1 Data collection and storage**

*(ii) If your app doesn’t include significant account-based features, let people use it without a log-in. Apps may not require users to enter personal information to function, except when directly relevant to the core functionality of the app or required by law.*

On a phone call I explained to him the app allows the user to open it, navigate around. But wont allow the user to create chat rooms or upload/share data within the rooms as it needs CloudKit authentication to store the data to then share it between users. According paragraph (ii) that was a significant account based feature to require authentication. He was fine with that.

Then he said he would still not be able to approve the app because CloudKit should only be used if the app intends to store data on the cloud. Data like, documents, photos, etc... according to him a chat app (WhatsApp a example) that stores images and text on the cloud to then share it between users is not actually storing data on the cloud and for that reason should not be using CloudKit and would be a definitive rejection.

**Designing for CloudKit documentation says:**

*You can represent all the persistent model objects in your app using a CloudKit schema. However, the CloudKit framework should not be used to replace model objects in your app and should not be used for storing objects locally. It is a service for moving data to and from iCloud and sharing data between users of your app.*

Not seeing where is my breach when the app:

1. only asks the user to authenticate when a core feature of the app is
   called
2. uses the authentication to store messages, images, etc... in
   the users iCloud account
3. uses the authentication to exchange this data that has been stored between users

After investing huge amounts of time and money in the app it is hard to accept a permanent rejection for such an odd reason. There is no documentation to sustain his argument or stop us from investing time/money with CloudKit wrongly.

Not sure where to go from here. Anyone with similar issue when using CloudKit?

Comment: While I can appreciate your frustration, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only Apple can approve apps; There is nothing that anyone on StackOverflow can do.  Even if someone says "I have an app that uses CloudKit in that way and it was approved", Apple still decides on a case-by-case basis what they will and won't approve.  There are also numerous cases of approved apps in the store that would not be approved today; things change.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. You point of view makes sense to me, so happy to get the question closed then. We may need a moderator to do that, I cannot.

Comment: It does sound like an odd reason. From Apple's examples and videos they definitely imply that CloudKit can be used for social photo and chat apps. Stupid question but have you tried to appeal the rejection? Someone else at Apple might have a different view... https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=appeal

Comment: @grimfrog I will most certainly do that as soon as they fix the submission bug on itunes connect that is stoping submissions. Do you still have any of the links where Apple express CloudKit being used on chat apps? If you do go ahead and add an answer. That will be a good answer to my question I recon.